# Add Build Action for ANTLR in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, antlr

One needs to run ANTLR to make ANTLR grammar file into source file.

How can I use Build Action in Visual Studio for this? How can I make an Action something like "Build Antlr" to run antlr to generate source code?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This page has an answer](https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/ANTLR3/pages/2687335/Integration+with+Development+Environments):

You need to add this line in your project file.
    `<Project DefaultTargets="Build" InitialTargets="GenerateAntlrCode" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">`

Answer (score 0):

Install [ANTLR Language Support extension for Visual Studio](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/25b991db-befd-441b-b23b-bb5f8d07ee9f).